# How to get Previous Value for Null Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the Below Data in my Table.

```
   | Id  |  FeeModeId   |Name        |   Amount|
   ---------------------------------------------
   | 1   |  NULL        | NULL       |   20    |
   | 2   |  1           | Quarter-1  |   5000  |
   | 3   |  NULL        | NULL       |   2000  |    
   | 4   |  2           | Quarter-2  |   8000  |
   | 5   |  NULL        | NULL       |   5000  |
   | 6   |  NULL        | NULL       |   2000  |
   | 7   |  3           | Quarter-3  |   6000  |
   | 8   |  NULL        | NULL       |   4000  |
```

How to write such query to get below output...

```
   | Id  |  FeeModeId   |Name        |   Amount|
   ---------------------------------------------
   | 1   |  NULL        | NULL       |   20    |
   | 2   |  1           | Quarter-1  |   5000  |
   | 3   |  1           | Quarter-1  |   2000  |    
   | 4   |  2           | Quarter-2  |   8000  |
   | 5   |  2           | Quarter-2  |   5000  |
   | 6   |  2           | Quarter-2  |   2000  |
   | 7   |  3           | Quarter-3  |   6000  |
   | 8   |  3           | Quarter-3  |   4000  |
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Thanx, Its helpful, but in my case previous value difference is not fix, some time 2 record, some time 3, it can be any range.

Comment: Looks as though in Oracle this [could be done](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-nov/o66asktom-099001.html) with `LAST_VALUE ... IGNORE NULLS` but SQL Server does not support the `IGNORE NULLS` option.

Comment: @Randy "...use a LAG function..." It would fantastic if you could post an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
    a.ID,
    ISNULL(a.FeeModeId, x.FeeModeId) FeeModeId,
    ISNULL(a.Name, x.Name) Name,
    a.Amount
from tbl a
outer apply
(select top 1 FeeModeId, Name 
    from tbl b 
    where b.ID<a.ID and 
        b.Amount is not null and 
        b.FeeModeId is not null and 
        a.FeeModeId is null order by ID desc)x
```

OR

```
select 
    ID,
    ISNULL(FeeModeId, bFeeModeId) FeeModeId,
    ISNULL(Name, bName) Name,
    Amount
From(
    select 
        a.ID , a.FeeModeId, a.Name, a.Amount, 
        b.ID bID, b.FeeModeId bFeeModeId, b.Name bName,
        MAX(b.FeeModeId) over (partition by a.ID) mx
    from tbl a left join tbl b on b.ID<a.ID
    and b.FeeModeId is not null
)x 
where bFeeModeId=mx or mx is null
```

Answer (score 22):

Since you are on SQL Server 2012... here is a version that uses that. It might be faster than other solutions but you have to test that on your data.

`sum() over()` will do a running sum ordered by `Id` adding `1` when there are a value in the column and keeping the current value for `null` values. The calculated running sum is then used to partition the result in `first_value() over()`. The first value ordered by `Id` for each "group" of rows generated by the running sum has the value you want.

```
select T.Id,
       first_value(T.FeeModeId) 
          over(partition by T.NF 
               order by T.Id 
               rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as FeeModeId,
       first_value(T.Name)      
          over(partition by T.NS 
               order by T.Id 
               rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as Name,
       T.Amount
from (
     select Id,
            FeeModeId,
            Name,
            Amount,
            sum(case when FeeModeId is null then 0 else 1 end) 
              over(order by Id) as NF,
            sum(case when Name is null then 0 else 1 end) 
              over(order by Id) as NS
     from YourTable
     ) as T
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a5213/2)

Something that will work pre SQL Server 2012:

```
select T1.Id,
       T3.FeeModeId,
       T2.Name,
       T1.Amount
from YourTable as T1
  outer apply (select top(1) Name
               from YourTable as T2
               where T1.Id >= T2.Id and
                     T2.Name is not null
               order by T2.Id desc) as T2
  outer apply (select top(1) FeeModeId
               from YourTable as T3
               where T1.Id >= T3.Id and
                     T3.FeeModeId is not null
               order by T3.Id desc) as T3
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a5213/1)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  T.ID,
  ISNULL(T.FeeModeId, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 FeeModeId 
        FROM TableName AS T1 
        WHERE ID < T.ID AND FeeModeId IS NOT NULL 
        ORDER BY ID DESC)) AS FeeModeId,
  ISNULL(Name,
    (SELECT TOP 1 Name 
    FROM TableName 
    WHERE ID < T.ID AND Name IS NOT NULL 
    ORDER BY ID DESC)) AS Name,
  T.Amount
FROM
  TableName AS T
```

Answer (score 2):

try this -

```
SELECT Id,
       CASE
         WHEN Feemodeid IS NOT NULL THEN
          Feemodeid
         ELSE
          (SELECT Feemodeid
             FROM Table_Name t_2
            WHERE t_2.Id = (SELECT MAX(Id)
                              FROM Table_Name t_3
                             WHERE t_3.Id < t_1.Id
                               AND Feemodeid IS NOT NULL))
        END Feemodeid,
       CASE
         WHEN NAME IS NOT NULL THEN
          NAME
         ELSE
          (SELECT NAME
             FROM Table_Name t_2
            WHERE t_2.Id = (SELECT MAX(Id)
                              FROM Table_Name t_3
                             WHERE t_3.Id < t_1.Id
                               AND NAME IS NOT NULL))
       END NAME,
       Amount
  FROM Table_Name t_1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
id  name
1   toto
2   NULL
3   NULL
4   titi
5   NULL
6   NULL
7   tutu
8   NULL
9   NULL


SELECT 
       id_table
       ,name
FROM 
       (
             SELECT
                    T_01.id AS 'id_table'
                    ,max(T_02.id) AS 'id_name'
             FROM
                    names AS T_01
                    cross join  
                    (
                          SELECT
                                 id
                                 ,name
                          FROM
                                 names
                          WHERE
                                 name IS NOT NULL
                    ) AS T_02 
             WHERE 
                    T_02.id <= T_01.id
             GROUP BY 
                    T_01.id
       ) AS tt02
       left join names
       ON names.id = tt02.id_name


id_table    name
1           toto
2           toto
3           toto
4           titi
5           titi
6           titi
7           tutu
8           tutu
9           tutu
```