# How to replace null values with previous known values in a column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

[image: Input File]

[image: Output]

I have tried using lead but obviously didn't work bcs of multiple nulls.and "last_value" with "ignore nulls" using partitions did n't workout bcs  "ignore nulls" function is not available in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I efficiently select the previous non-null value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987791/how-do-i-efficiently-select-the-previous-non-null-value)

Answer (score 0):

i suggest write pgsql function which find all rows where service is null, then update this value to (previous or next) fisrt where value is not null