# Postgres - Issue with partition sub-query

Tags: postgresql, subquery, window-functions

The following statement work fine:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
woas.assessmentid,
woas.workorderid FROM wo_assessment
    LEFT JOIN wo_assessment woas ON woas.assessmentid = woas.assessmentid
LEFT JOIN wo_group_info wogi ON woas.assessmentid=wogi.assessmentid
```

However when I add the below sub query, I get a generic error about the FROM clause 'ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM"'

```
first_value(wogi.groupid ) over (partition by value_partition ORDER BY woas.assessmentid) 
     FROM (SELECT woas.assessmentid,wogi.groupid, sum(case when wogi.groupid is null then 0 else 1 end) over (ORDER BY woas.assessmentid) as value_partition
FROM wo_assessment
ORDER BY  woas.assessmentid) as q
```

Here is the complete code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
woas.assessmentid,
woas.workorderid,
first_value(wogi.groupid ) over (partition by value_partition ORDER BY woas.assessmentid) 
     FROM (SELECT woas.assessmentid,wogi.groupid, sum(case when wogi.groupid is null then 0 else 1 end) over (ORDER BY woas.assessmentid) as value_partition
FROM wo_assessment
ORDER BY  woas.assessmentid) as q FROM wo_assessment
    LEFT JOIN wo_assessment woas ON woas.assessmentid = woas.assessmentid
LEFT JOIN wo_group_info wogi ON woas.assessmentid=wogi.assessmentid
```

I cant for the life of me understand why it wont validate, any help greatly appreciated.

**Latest attempt, it now says by sub query returns more that one result.**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
woas.assessmentid,
woas.workorderid,

first_value(wogi.groupid ) over (partition by value_partition ORDER BY woas.assessmentid) ,

(SELECT woas.assessmentid,wogi.groupid, sum(case when wogi.groupid is null then 0 else 1 end) over (ORDER BY wo.assessmentid) as value_partition
FROM wo_assessment wo LEFT JOIN wo_assessment woas ON woas.assessmentid = wo.assessmentid WHERE woas.assessmentid = wo.assessmentid ORDER BY  wo.assessmentid) as q FROM wo_assessment

LEFT JOIN wo_assessment woas ON woas.assessmentid = woas.assessmentid
LEFT JOIN wo_group_info wogi ON woas.assessmentid=wogi.assessmentid
```

Comment: You can have at most one `from` clause...

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your query doesn't make a whole lot of sense right now.

Comment: Please take a look at my earlier post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48543630/populate-zero-values-in-column-with-next-value-greater-than-zero I am trying to take the select query from this post and include it as a sub select as part of an over arching select statement. I have made some progress. Hopefully my new code (update above) makes a bit more sense

Comment: You are still referencing a table within the subquery that is joined to *outside* of the subquery. I am somewhat surprised that this even runs.

Comment: I will take a look at the earlier post, thanks for linking to it.