# Fetch last available value if there is NULL

Tags: postgresql, ifnull

I have a table that is essentially a purchases table that has purchase prices. When a purchase is made, it is recorded at an hour. Like in the table, ABC-123 was purchased on 2022-1-20 at 12:00. I want the NULL values to show 20 as long as a new purchase price is not punched in. Same for the other id_code.

| id_code | hour | purchase_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC-123 | 2022-1-20 12:00 | 20 |
| ABC-123 | 2022-1-20 13:00 | NULL |
| ABC-123 | 2022-1-20 14:00 | NULL |
| BCD-123 | 2022-1-20 12:00 | 35 |
| BCD-123 | 2022-1-20 13:00 | 36 |
| BCD-123 | 2022-1-20 14:00 | NULL |

The output table will look like this:
It will replace the NULLs with the previously available price for its particular id_code.

| id_code | hour | purchase_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC-123 | 2022-1-20 12:00 | 20 |
| ABC-123 | 2022-1-20 13:00 | 20 |
| ABC-123 | 2022-1-20 14:00 | 20 |
| BCD-123 | 2022-1-20 12:00 | 35 |
| BCD-123 | 2022-1-20 13:00 | 36 |
| BCD-123 | 2022-1-20 14:00 | 36 |

I did find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987791/how-do-i-efficiently-select-the-previous-non-null-value) but that seems to not work because my IDs are not incremental integers I think.

Comment: You can't do that in SQL. You must correct the `purchase_price` while you're reading the records.

Comment: have you tried using the example you found and ordering by the hour instead of id?

Comment: you can use lag() for retrieving previous row value

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view with an aggregate function. Try this :

```
CREATE VIEW test_view AS
( SELECT id_code
       , hour
       , (array_agg(purchase_price) FILTER (WHERE purchase_price IS NOT NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY id_code ORDER BY hour DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING))[1]
    FROM test
)
```

Result :

```
id_code hour                array_agg
ABC-123 2022-01-20 12:00:00 20
ABC-123 2022-01-20 13:00:00 20
ABC-123 2022-01-20 14:00:00 20
BCD-123 2022-01-20 12:00:00 35
BCD-123 2022-01-20 13:00:00 36
BCD-123 2022-01-20 14:00:00 36
```

see the demo in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2e82b9aad935daff9447743ee5bcdae5).

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Is there a way to get it done without creating a view?

Comment: yes you can just execute the query if you don't need the view