# PostgreSQL users and balances - use previous balance for user in time series if value is missing

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

Given the following tables:

**users**:

| name |
| --- |
| alice |
| bob |

**balances**:

| id | user_name | date | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | alice | 2022-01-01 | 100 |
| 2 | alice | 2022-01-03 | 200 |
| 3 | alice | 2022-01-04 | 300 |
| 4 | bob | 2022-01-01 | 400 |
| 5 | bob | 2022-01-02 | 500 |
| 6 | bob | 2022-01-05 | 600 |

I would like to get a full list of all days from the first available to the last for all users, replacing NULL balances with the last available balance for that user.

This is what I have so far:

```sql
select u.name, s.day, b.balance
from users u
cross join (select generate_series(min(day)::date, max(day)::date, interval '1 day')::date as day from balances) s
left join balances b on b.user_name = u.name and s.day = b.day
order by u.name, s.day 
;
```

[SQL Fiddle Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/tmvj3Eam)

I have tried `LAG()` and some other examples found here but none of them seem to get the right last balance for the user.

Answer (score 1):

We group every `balance` with the `nulls` that come after it by using `count() over()` and then we use `max() over()` to give the entire group the same value.

```
select name
      ,day
      ,max(balance) over(partition by name, grp order by day) as balance
from 
(
select      u.name
           ,s.day
           ,b.balance
           ,count(case when b.balance is not null then 1 end) over(partition by u.name order by s.day) as grp
from        users u
cross join (select generate_series(min(day)::date, max(day)::date, interval '1 day')::date as day from balances) s
left join   balances b on b.user_name = u.name and s.day = b.day
order by    u.name, s.day 
) t
```

| name | day | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| alice | 2022-01-01 | 100 |
| alice | 2022-01-02 | 100 |
| alice | 2022-01-03 | 200 |
| alice | 2022-01-04 | 300 |
| alice | 2022-01-05 | 300 |
| bob | 2022-01-01 | 400 |
| bob | 2022-01-02 | 500 |
| bob | 2022-01-03 | 500 |
| bob | 2022-01-04 | 500 |
| bob | 2022-01-05 | 600 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AEMXeA6d)

Comment: This solution adds the sum of all previous balances. I need it to add the last balance value. E.g. bob's 2022-01-05 balance should be 600

Answer (score 0):

Based on [How do I efficiently select the previous non-null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987791/how-do-i-efficiently-select-the-previous-non-null-value), I ended up getting successful results with the following query:

```sql
select
  name, 
  day, 
  first_value(balance) over (partition by x.name, value_partition order by day) as balance
from (
  select 
    u.name as name, 
    s.day as day, 
    b.balance as balance,
    sum(case when b.balance is null then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by u.name order by s.day) as value_partition
  from users u
  cross join (select generate_series(min(day)::date, max(day)::date, interval '1 day')::date as day from balances) s
  left join balances b on b.user_name = u.name and s.day = b.day
) x
order by x.name, x.day
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZKpbaKrt)