# Last_value with IGNORE NULLS in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a time series that with null values.  I want to be replace each null value with the most recent non-non value.  From what I've researched, Oracle SQL can easily accomplish this using Last_value with IGNORE NULLS.  Is there a similar way to accomplish this using SQL Server 2016?  Otherwise I'm just going to code it using C#, but felt using SQL would be faster, cleaner, and easier.

```
Sec SCORE
1   Null
2   Null
3   5
4   Null
5   8
6   7
7   Null
```

Should be replaced with:

```
Sec SCORE
1   Null
2   Null
3   5
4   5
5   8
6   7
7   7
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Previous Value for Null Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669620/how-to-get-previous-value-for-null-values)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with two cumulative operations:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(score, max(score) over (partition by maxid)) as newscore
from (select t.*,
             max(case when score is not null then id end) over (order by id) as maxid
      from t
     ) t;
```

The innermost subquery gets the most recent id where there is a value.  The outermost one "spreads" that value to the subsequent rows.

If you actually want to update the table, you can incorporate this easily into an `update`.  But, Oracle cannot do that (easily), so I'm guessing this is not necessary....

Comment: Genius! Does exactly what I need.  However, I plan on doing this often and on millions of rows.  It took about 1 minute to do the above on 3 million records.  Would I get significant speed benefits if I switched to Oracle Express and used last_value with IGNORE NULLS?

Comment: @TrevorD . . . You would have to test that yourself.  Of course, running two window functions takes longer than running one; I'm not sure if it worth the effort to switch databases for that gain.

Comment: Damn, this is really good. Sadly I could never write such good SQL like this :@

Comment: It only taking max values not if there any min value before null, ideally it should capture before null values

Comment: @MayankAwasthi . . . This answers the question that was asked here.  If you have your own question, then ask as a new question.  And by the way, this is not calculating a cumulative max.  Look at the data in the question and this does what the OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

If performance is an issue, I suggest the solution from this article:

[The Last non NULL Puzzle](https://www.itprotoday.com/software-development/last-non-null-puzzle)

His final solution, while dense, does perform excellently with a linear query plan without any joins. Here is an example implementation I've used which carries the last customer name through a type2 scd staging table. In this staging table, NULL represents no update, and `'*** DELETED ***'` represents an explicit set to NULL. The following cleans this up to resemble an actual SCD record excellently:

```
WITH [SampleNumbered] AS (
    SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [SampleId] ORDER BY [StartDatetime] ) AS [RowNumber]
    FROM [dbo].[SampleDimStage]
), [SamplePrep] AS (
    SELECT  [SampleId]
        ,   [StartDatetime]
        ,   CAST([RowNumber] AS BINARY(8)) + CAST([SampleGroupId] AS VARBINARY(255)) AS [BinarySampleGroupId]
        ,   CAST([RowNumber] AS BINARY(8)) + CAST([SampleStatusCode] AS VARBINARY(255)) AS [BinarySampleStatusCode]
    FROM [SampleNumbered]
), [SampleCleanUp] AS (
    SELECT  [SampleId]
        ,   [StartDatetime]
        ,   CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX([BinarySampleGroupId]) OVER( PARTITION BY [SampleId] ORDER BY [StartDatetime] )
                , 9, 255) AS VARCHAR(255)) AS [LastSampleGroupId]
        ,   CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX([BinarySampleStatusCode]) OVER( PARTITION BY [SampleId] ORDER BY [StartDatetime] )
                , 9, 255) AS VARCHAR(255)) AS [LastSampleStatusCode]
        ,   LEAD([StartDatetime]) OVER( PARTITION BY [SampleId] ORDER BY [StartDatetime] ) AS [EndDatetime]
    FROM [SamplePrep]
)
SELECT  CAST([SampleId] AS NUMERIC(18)) AS [SampleId]
    ,   CAST(NULLIF([sc].[LastSampleGroupId],'*** DELETED ***') AS NUMERIC(18)) AS [GroupId]
    ,   CAST(NULLIF([sc].[LastSampleStatusCode],'*** DELETED ***') AS CHAR(3)) AS [SampleStatusCode]
    ,   [StartDatetime]
    ,   [sc].[EndDatetime]
FROM [SampleCleanUp] [sc];
```

If your sort key is some sort of integer, you can completely skip the first CTE and cast that directly to binary.