# How to update a column till the value changed in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I've table like the following

```
TData   Ucode   Fla
Data1   123 w
Data2   123 NULL
Data3   123 NULL
Data4   123 n
Data5   123 NULL
```

The excepted result

```
TData   Ucode   Fla
Data1   123 w
Data2   123 W
Data3   123 W
Data4   123 n
Data5   123 n
```

I need to update "Fla" where "Ucode" till the "Fla" changes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Previous Value for Null Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669620/how-to-get-previous-value-for-null-values)

Answer (score -1):

you need to use an update statement

`UPDATE table_name
SET w='w'.
WHERE w is NULL;`

it may be worth looking at `CASE` statements as well (https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/case.php)

Comment: If you read his question or look at his sample data and expected output, you'll see that this isn't what he wants to do.

Comment: Thanks for you kind replay. But I need to update "Fla" till changes by Ucode

Comment: your answer is not what I mean.