# SQL: Fill NULL values in time series with closest preceding existing value

Tags: sql-server, replace, null, time-series

I created the following statement:

```
SELECT
    convert(varchar, cal.[Datum], 104) as Datum
    , snb.[Kurs] as FX_CHF_EUR_SNB
FROM [DM_MAH].[dbo].[SNB_Kurs] snb
RIGHT JOIN [dbo].[Dim_Kalender] cal
  ON snb.Datum = cal.Datum
WHERE cal.Datum >= '2019-05-14' and cal.Datum <= GETDATE()
Order by cal.Datum desc
```

Which gives me the following result:

```
Datum       FX_CHF_EUR_SNB
12.05.2020  1.051500
11.05.2020  1.052300
10.05.2020  NULL
09.05.2020  NULL
08.05.2020  1.052800
07.05.2020  1.053200
06.05.2020  1.052800
05.05.2020  1.052500
04.05.2020  1.054700
03.05.2020  NULL
02.05.2020  NULL
01.05.2020  NULL
30.04.2020  1.056900
29.04.2020  1.056000
```

As you can see there are `NULL` values for different dates in the time series. This is expected because where I get the data from they don't have values for every day of the year. For my purpose I need the completed time series with every day of the year though, which is why I joined it with a calendar table. So far so good.

What I am not able to do, is, fill the `NULL` values with the closest preceding existing value of the time series. So here an example of what I want to achieve with the given data:

```
Datum       FX_CHF_EUR_SNB
12.05.2020  1.051500
11.05.2020  1.052300
10.05.2020  **1.052800**
09.05.2020  **1.052800**
08.05.2020  1.052800
```

> so the values for 09.05.2020 and 10.05.2020 in this case should be copied from the 08.05.2020

Would be glad if anyone knew how to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Previous Value for Null Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669620/how-to-get-previous-value-for-null-values)

Comment: This helped, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach uses a correlated subquery to choose the correct non `NULL` value to report from the `SNB_Kurs` table:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar, cal.[Datum], 104) AS Datum,
    (SELECT TOP 1 snb.[Kurs] FROM [DM_MAH].[dbo].[SNB_Kurs] snb
     WHERE snb.Datum <= cal.Datum AND snb.Datum IS NOT NULL
     ORDER BY snb.Datum DESC) AS FX_CHF_EUR_SNB
FROM [dbo].[Dim_Kalender] cal
WHERE cal.Datum >= '2019-05-14' AND cal.Datum <= GETDATE()
ORDER BY cal.Datum DESC;
```

Comment: With this i was able to solve my problem! Thank you.